# inter & intra stream in A Multimedia Synchronization System

Tags: stream, multimedia, qos

I have a question that's required in my material to succeed
the tutor hasn't explained it, nor the material in my Multimedia Course.In Addition, I have searched the internet for it, and return empty handed.
the question is the following:

Suppose we want to design and implement a system to manage the synchronization between the following media in a multimodal system.
Knowing that the time interval for each packet of :
1.  audio medium is 40 ms 
2.  video medium is 20 ms
3.  haptic medium is 10 ms
and with a certain time the audio packet number 32, and the video packet number 50, and the haptic packet number 41 must be synchronized.

Audio media stream

30  31   32 29  33  34  38  35  36  37
Video media stream

50  53  51  52  53  55  56  57  58  54
Haptic media stream

40  41  42  43  44  48  49  50  51  52

•   What are the key points of the desired synchronization system in two modes in elastic and inelastic (real time) traffic. (Note: provide the calculation need for inter and intra media synchronization).
•   Which of the above medium have been more affected by the jitter and which have been more affected by the packet loss?

---

now, for you, who may say I'm a lazy or something like that, I want to say that I really tried to try and solve the problem, and here is my theories about the solution:

(the following is a demonstration of what I think intra media means)
the audio packet that requires sync. is 80 ms away 
the video packet needs for sync. needs 0 ms (as it's the first packet)
the haptic packet needs 10 ms (as it's one packet away)

so, in my point of view, audio is the slowest, so I have 2 possible ways to solve it:
either omit the first two packets from audio, and the 1st haptic packet, so all can begin at the same time.
Or, I have to delay the video and the haptic, so they can all be sync in the end.

I'm really afraid of this question, please give me a hand on this one.
Thanks forwards for your precious comments.